# Where are libertine documents stored?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, libreoffice, m10, libertine

I have been editing documents downloaded from Dropbox in LibreOffice on my M10 tablet, but I can't find the documents in the user space on `/phablet/Documents/` etc. Same thing with files downloaded through Firefox, can't locate them on the hard drive in the File Manager or any other Ubuntu Touch apps.

Is there a way to save these files in the folders accessible under `/Phablet/`?

Answer (score 1):

I just saved a test document in LibreOffice to take a look at this. I tried to save it in phablet but via FileManager I found it in `/home/phablet/.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/puritine`

I guess I can see the logic of that for security but it isn't great for users in cases like this.

I can't see an easy way to break out of the libertine jail and save wherever you want- which I guess is a feature more than a bug.

The best thing might be to try [`mount --bind`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/mount.8.html). It's a way to mount one folder as another. I am not so familiar with it, but it is described as a solution to a similiar problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55710/how-can-i-access-a-directory-outside-a-chroot-from-within-it).

One thing to be careful of, the accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620740/recommended-way-to-install-regularcli-deb-packages-on-ubuntu-phone/623311#623311) says that if you do mount chroot directories ". You will need to take extra care when doing so, if you wish to delete the chroot from your phone, or perform other destructive actions".

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great, thanks! Now I can at least "sudo cp" to my /home/phablet/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mounting `/home/phablet/.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/puritine` somewhere in home you can also create a softlink to that directory in `/home/phablet/Documents`

`cd ~/Documents;ln -s /home/phablet/.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/puritine Puritinedocs` should do the trick.

Edit: Just checked, this works and file permissions are fine. As a bonus the softlinks will survive reboots.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I thought that symlinks wouldn't work from a chroot, based on the accepted answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/557733/ln-s-vs-mount-bind).  I must check this out later on.

Comment: That they won't work **from** a chroot sounds logical but this is **to** an existing folder....

Comment: Addition: I'm not shure about file ownership in the Puritine libertine-container filesystem, will check later today.

Answer (score 0):

You XDG documents folders are automatically bind-mounted into the Libertine container.  In other words, if you save a LibreOffice document in your Documents folder, it's saved to /home/phablet/Documents.

The XDG documents folders include Documents, Music, Pictures, and Videos.