# Can we just use symbolic link instead of 'mount --bind'?

Tags: mount, filesystem, symbolic-link

Recently I came to know about the `mount --bind` command but there is something that I can't understand clearly. Suppose I have a disk partition and I mounted it to a mount point /bkup using this command.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /bkup
```

If I want to make that /home/bkup directory appear as ~/bkup, I could do

```
sudo mount --bind /bkup ~/bkup
```

But how is it different from

```
ln -s /bkup ~/bkup
```

in effect? Why should I use `mount --bind` when I can do the same thing with `ln -s` command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ln -s and mount --bind?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557733/what-is-the-difference-between-ln-s-and-mount-bind)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mount --bind` is more like an equivalent of a "hard link" to a directory (well, you cannot create hard links to directories, but this is closest you can get), while symbolic link is... well, a symbolic link.

Myself I found two cases where the difference may be important:

1. running some service in a chroot. Symbolic links from inside a chroot jail to outside of a chroot jail don't work, while `mount --bind` works.
2. sharing some directory over a network. You cannot share a symbolic link, but you can share directory mounted over `mount --bind`.

You must also be very careful with programs that by design distinguish between symbolic links and actual directories, like `rsync`. Trying to run `rsync` on a symbolic link to a directory may give you completely other results than you expect.